# How to fetch utf parameter from url?

Tags: javascript, url, character-encoding, get

I got from server words which contains utf characters like Ž,ć and so on....
I put in url parameters and my url looks like `?id=229&name=%8eena%20mini%3f`

I am fetching parameters from url with js function

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

and it parses first id parameter but on second (when I have utf before encoded in url) it breaks.

```
var id = getURLParameter('id');//works
var id = getURLParameter('name');//breaks when have utf
```

How to fetch that parameter when it has utf from url ?
(On page I have `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`)

Comment: "it breaks" means what? What happens?

Comment: Your encoding is broken; `%8eena%20mini%3f` what is `%8` representing? its not valid.. `encodeURIComponent("Žeena mini?") === "%C5%BDeena%20mini%3F"` which would decode fine

Comment: decodeURI((RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1])

Answer (score 1):

Whatever is encoding `Žena` to `%8eena` is not using UTF-8 encoding, it's using Windows-1252 enoding, since `Ž` is represented as `8e` in that character set.

In UTF-8, `Ž` is represented as `c5 bd`, so you should expect your URL to contain `%c5%bd` if the form had the correct encoding.

Looks like you need `<meta charset="utf-8">` on the previous page, or at the very least the attribute `accept-charset="utf-8"` on the form that you submit.

See also: [Is there any benefit to adding accept-charset="UTF-8" to HTML forms, if the page is already in UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719974/is-there-any-benefit-to-adding-accept-charset-utf-8-to-html-forms-if-the-page)