# how to convert altcodes to html code in php

Tags: php, forms

I'm working on a website where I have a form, if I enter text everything works as it should but if I enter special characters like `☺ ☻ ♥ ♦` so it just becomes a lot of `??` in the database. So is there any way to convert them to html code?

Example: `♥` convention served to `&#9829;`

Comment: convert to & # 9 8 2 9 ; (delite the whitespace)

Comment: try using php utf8_encode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `htmlentities` http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

You'll need to know which encoding the input data uses (obviously). The default is UTF8.

```
$encoded = htmlentities( $input, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, 'UTF-8', false );
```

Note that I've set the final parameter `false` (default is `true`). That is so that users can type, for example, `&amp;` and it will convert to `&`. But maybe you want the default behaviour (`&amp;` -> `&amp;`)

The encoding which is used when sending POST data can be set in the `form` tag:

```
<form method="post" action="myscript.php" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

But see here for a discussion: [Is there any benefit to adding accept-charset="UTF-8" to HTML forms, if the page is already in UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3719974/1180785)

Comment: thanks for the answer :) the ♥ and ♦ converted as I wanted byt ☺and ☻ is stil ?? can it be fixed?

Comment: maybe your encoding isn't UTF-8. How are you sending the text to the server?

Comment: No I mean where is that coming from? It will be sent to your server (from a form) in a particular encoding. See here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3.3 (I assume that it defaults to the encoding of your page)

Comment: I'm using this line in the html head <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >