# Greek characters in html forms and storing to variables

Tags: python, html, sql, bottle

I am trying to make an html page which will have an interaction with a SQL database.I am using python as language and bottle+pymysql . I want my form to accept greek characters , so I can put them into the variables and later use them for my database.I am using **accept charset** in my form but not sure what it does and it does't work , too.

For example,I would like something like this
name = 'ΟΝΟΜΑ'
surname = 'ΕΠΙΘΕΤΟ'

My code works for english input , but my database contains only greek so it's a real need.

```
@app.route('/b1') # or @route('/login')
def b1():
    return '''
        <form action="/b1" method="post" accept-charset="foobar utt-8" >
            Name           : <input name="name" type="text" /><br>
            Surname        : <input name="surname" type="text" /><br>
            Birth Year-From: <input name="from" type="text" /><br>
            Birth Year-To  : <input name="to" type="text" /><br>
            <input value="Submit" type="submit" />
        </form>
'''

@app.post('/b1',method='POST') # or @route('/login', method='POST')
def do_b1():
    name = request.forms.get('name')
    surname = request.forms.get('surname')
    dfrom = request.forms.get('from')
    dto = request.forms.get('to')

   try:
       query = '...'
       curs.execute(query)
   except:
       yield "\n Failed to get data from base<br/>"
   yield name
   yield surname
   yield dfrom
   yield dto
```

Comment: Do you mean `utf-8`?

Comment: yes ! Should I change the title ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719974/is-there-any-benefit-to-adding-accept-charset-utf-8-to-html-forms-if-the-page